# Using Highcharts stock type feature for non-stock data (R)

Tags: r, r-highcharter

I am working with a time-series which is not stock market data. I would like to use highcharter in R to make interactive visualization. I made a chart like this for the time being:.

## dummy data

```
library(tidyverse)
library(highcharter)   


data(economics_long, package = "ggplot2")

economics_long2 <- filter(economics_long,
                          variable %in% c("pop", "uempmed", "unemploy"))

hchart(economics_long2, "line", hcaes(x = "date", y = "value01", group = "variable"))
```

I am wondering, is there any way to add a date filter at the top of this chart like the date filter in type = 'stock' chart in highcharter. Something similar to this picture:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I think in basic solution you can create own widget / gadget.
That is kind of start for it - fully functional - you can style it better for your purpose.

```
library(shiny)
library(miniUI)
library(highcharter)
library(tidyverse)


hightchart_filter <- function(data) {

  ui <- miniPage(
    miniContentPanel(

        # Dates ####
        dateInput("date_start", "start_date", value = "1900-01-01",   width = "25%"),
        dateInput("date_end", "end_date",  value = "2100-01-01", width = "25%"),

        # Highchart ####
        highchartOutput("high_plot", height = "500px")
      )
    )


  server <- function(input, output, session) {

    # update for data boxes
    updateDateInput(session, "date_start", value = data$date %>% min())
    updateDateInput(session, "date_end", value = data$date %>% max())

    # filter data
    data_filtered <- reactive({
      data %>% filter(between(date, input$date_start, input$date_end))
    })

    # Highchart ####
    output$high_plot <- renderHighchart({
      hchart(data_filtered(), "line", hcaes(x = "date", y = "value01", group = "variable"))
    })

  }

  runGadget(ui, server)
}
```

and run it :

```
hightchart_filter(economics_long)
```

Comment: Thanks! I thought it was a way without implementing shinny app

Comment: Yes. I understand - I also though how to do it in some kind of options way. In the end is not really shiny app - you just create a widget / gadget - it means is just function and is called as function   

https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/gadgets.html  

- you don't need to create a shinny app with server / UI structure - you dont't care about it. I think that Highcharter itself is a gadget   

http://www.htmlwidgets.org/showcase_highcharts.html   

that means if you add something to it to improve functionality it will not really change a way to call it.